# Can I use classic Borland & clang compiler for the same application

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm looking for some advice on how to migrate a C++Builder 5 project to Embarcadero C++Builder 11.

Some of the DLLs can only be compiled with the 'classic' Borland compiler. The rest can be compile with the Clang-compiler.

Can I use 2 different compilers in the same application?

Comment: C++ Builder 5 is **21** years old.  It is an antique.  You should fix your code so it works with a modern compiler.

Comment: Most likely with some caveats. The one thing to be aware of is that they will probably not share the same C/C++ runtime. If there's a shared C/C++ runtime that your code depends on, you may have to ship the old and the new version. If there's memory allocated (new'd or malloc'd) by one EXE/DLL, it can't be deleted/free'd by the other if it's a different runtime. Similar thing for file handles and other objects managed by the runtime.  If you already using a shared (DLL) runtime and are statically linking to it instead, it won't likely be an issue.

Comment: What is a classic compiler?

Comment: So long as everything is written to be C89 compatible -- you can -- but why would you. Never use a compiler last updated in the last century...

Comment: @S.M. C++Builder includes multiple C++ compilers for cross-platform developmemt. Most of the supported platforms only have 1 Clang-based compiler. But a couple of the platforms have 2 compilers, one based on clang, and one based on old Borland tech. For those platforms, the IDE allows projects to pick which of the two compilers to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for some advice on how to migrate a C++Builder 5 project to Embarcadero C++Builder 11.

That is a very massive upgrade. A LOT has changed over the decades between the two versions. I hope you are reading the docs in Embarcadero's [Migration and Upgrade Center](https://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/migration-upgrade-center), for starters.

> Some of the DLLs can only be compiled with the 'classic' Borland compiler. The rest can be compile with the Clang-compiler.
>
> Can I use 2 different compilers in the same application?

If the EXE and DLLs are all compiled to be self-contained (ie, no Runtime Packages, no Dynamic RTL, no shared Memory Manager, not sharing object files, etc), and they all follow safe guidelines about memory management and using only safe and compatible POD data types across the DLL boundaries, etc, then in that regard, it should be possible to compile each module with a different compiler.